# Javascript Parsing JSON with Escape Characters

Tags: javascript, android, json, android-pay

So I have a JSON object that is returned from an Android Pay API call that I need to pull the data out and process it.  Problem is that it contains backslashes that must be preserved.  I have looked at lots of threads on this but nothing seems to work.  How can I parse out the key/value pairs from data below and preserve the backslashes in the data?

```
{"ephemeralPublicKey":"BE1Ai3\/HjtEon0JAz+9jK8GmF9vzmXpDACcpjsXDD5EkP7HmhdXrNjVMdi58itYNGH6HoZvlOY65qvHWRwS0pu8=","encryptedMessage":"BIrMosJ9dQSeCL0ImJPhml3++grM6AvW9qLkTkp6I\/gt1q+JsFB9rm9Ndzdjd7UuN\/RJm6osMHd1UDIi84VlQljJKMQnRQKrQrqx15jlNOBlGrALOTY3TQIYyWOvMB8I\/Kr6yFduvy+b2IVR+3GPDjI4J3PKHd+xPLh4WvXhmBckda54T3vVW\/2Toxi02IC1w\/n5AkTlKfem6XTvw9sC","tag":"GEyeDyeNrXn3T2GYHFOL4WeQLBRBVt7PCKmr9OfJa3M="}
```

Comment: not sure if I am following you. If that's a json object, what do you need to parse? if you assign this result to a variable like `data` then you should be able to get it by `data.ephemeralPublicKey`

Comment: I assigned it to a variable and printed out data.ephemeralPublicKey like you suggested but it comes out undefined.

Comment: so your data looks like json but in reality it is plain string. try `var data = JSON.parse('{"ephemeralPublicKey"..........}'); console.log(data.ephemeralPublicKey)` note single quotes.

Comment: That gives the same result I am trying to fix in that the output stripes out the backslashes '\'.  So for example, BKxU\/qD1P turns into BKxU/qD1P.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
var data = {"ephemeralPublicKey":"BE1Ai3\/HjtEon0JAz+9jK8GmF9vzmXpDACcpjsXDD5EkP7HmhdXrNjVMdi58itYNGH6HoZvlOY65qvHWRwS0pu8=","encryptedMessage":"BIrMosJ9dQSeCL0ImJPhml3++grM6AvW9qLkTkp6I\/gt1q+JsFB9rm9Ndzdjd7UuN\/RJm6osMHd1UDIi84VlQljJKMQnRQKrQrqx15jlNOBlGrALOTY3TQIYyWOvMB8I\/Kr6yFduvy+b2IVR+3GPDjI4J3PKHd+xPLh4WvXhmBckda54T3vVW\/2Toxi02IC1w\/n5AkTlKfem6XTvw9sC","tag":"GEyeDyeNrXn3T2GYHFOL4WeQLBRBVt7PCKmr9OfJa3M="};

var obj = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'));
console.log("Value: " + obj.ephemeralPublicKey);
```

Comment: you can't do a `.replace` on a JSON object

Answer (score 1):

I see the code is working, what is the point in your question?

you should escape the backslash character, like this.

```
var str = '{"ephemeralPublicKey":"BE1Ai3\\/HjtEon0JA"}';//...string response from api 
var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace('\\/','\\\\/'));
obj.ephemeralPublicKey
```

Comment: JSON.parse will parse out the backslashes.  See example comment above.  I editted the OP so hopefully the question is more clear.

Comment: Updated the answer, replace str by your object string value returned from the API.

Comment: That didn't work...it said "unexpected token e in JSON at position 12"

Comment: This actually didn't fully work.  It only found the first backslash but the rest were left out.  I have accepted my answer as the correct method because it matches all backslashes in the result returned from API call.

Comment: Yes, you are right but for the written code (for the sample value) it works fine, if you want to match all backslashes, you could use regex format with global option ('g')